# How to check if enough information is provided and if no give the user a prompt telling "not enough info"

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want a code block which will prompt the user if they havent mentioned time or they have given a input except a int something like this

```
if time != int
await ctx.send("Please give a time in mins")
await ctx.message.delete()
return
```

the below is the thing i have wrote currently

```
@client.command(aliases = ["among"])
    async def amongus(ctx , time):
        amongus = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, id = 833963462505136129)
    
        await ctx.message.delete()
        await ctx.send(f"{amongus.mention} wanna play among us in {time} mins?")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To compare variable types we use `isinstance`

```py
if isinstance(time, int):
    # Correct type
else:
    # Invalid type
```

Though discord.py by default assumes that the arguments are strings, you can either typehint the `time` argument to an int so discord.py converts them for us or check if it's a digit with `string.isdigit()` (you can also use a try-except block)

```py
# Typehinting
@client.command(aliases = ["among"])
async def amongus(ctx , time: int): # Raises `commands.BadArgument` if the conversion fails
    ...


# Checking if it's a digit
@client.command(aliases = ["among"])
async def amongus(ctx , time):
    if time.isdigit():
        time = int(time)
        # Correct type
    else:
        # Incorrect type


# try-except block
@client.command(aliases = ["among"])
async def amongus(ctx , time):
    try:
        time = int(time)
    except ValueError:
        # incorrect type
    else:
        # correct type
        await ctx.send(f"{amongus.mention} wanna play among us in {time} mins?")
```

Comment: if i want to send a msg saying please enter time in mins if the valued enter isnt a int where will that come?

Comment: Where the `incorrect type` comments are, in the first case with the typehinting you should do it in the error handler